# Слитно или раздельно?

Tags: частица-не

Здравствуйте! Это будет название статьи - "Неотступившие ходатаи". Верно ли написано "неотступившие"? Или все-таки следует писать раздельно? Насколько я понимаю, это причастие без зависящих от него слов, и с не оно пишется слитно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы все правильно понимаете. "Неотступившие" в данном контексте пишется слитно. Объяснение вы сами привели.